Free space path loss and Rician fading
Let a be a qam symbols vector , they pass through ofdm modulator by applying ifft and adding cyclic prefix and I apply comm.RicianChannel function for modeling rician fading I want to introduce also free space path loss (Friis equation)
Where have I put it ?

Does this answer your question? Free space path loss and ofdm

If what I wrote there wasn't explicit enough: Linearity holds for all components you want to combine. As before, you can figure this out yourself: What changes depending on the order of operations?

The statistics of Rice fading assume any path loss is modeled by the Rician model. Introducing separate free space path loss seems to be a clash of physical model (there's keyhole channels, where we could talk about that, but then you'd need to explain in much more depth how this works). So, first step, don't throw together effects just because you can – you need to make sure the thing you're modelling physically makes sense. So, in case you really want to combine a Free Space Path Loss with a Rician channel, you'll have to explain what your physical reality that you're modelling with that

… looks like! We can help you mathematically and algorithmically capture that, but for that we first need a physical model that you want to build in your simulation. You're not giving us that, so it's impossible to actually tell you how these effects would interact.

thank you for your reply , I want to analyze the effect of free space path loss in rician fading on ofdm symbol

Do you know the comm.RicianChannel function available on Matlab ?

How can I combine the application of this function with the Friis equation C/4pif*d on ofdm symbol ?

again, the free-space pass loss is already part of Rician fading. Done. You need to do nothing more. All you need to do is select the parameters of the comm.RicianChannel as appropriate for your physical model.

the only parameter of comm.RicianChannel that is related to path loss I think is AveragePathGains ?

yes, you have the shape parameter from the Rice distribution, which gives you influence on how the powers from the indirect paths compare to the power of the direct path, and the scale parameter, which gives you influence on how much total power you get. So, that fully encodes the free space path loss.

OK, Thanks for your replies
